# Configuration problem with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to build a Spring application with Eclipse. Since I've added the DAO layer with Hibernate this exception appear when I try to access to my web service with a browser.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)

The Spring JAR is in the "Libraries" of the Eclipse project and  Eclipse doesn't advise me about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is not only one spring jar. For the orm classes you need the `spring-orm-x.jar`. You'll need `spring-beans`, `spring-context` as well.

Comment: THX. spring-orm.jar was missing. I've added it in Eclipse but same errors. I've checked the WAR and it contains spring-orm.jar and spring-beans, spring-context, hibernate-core, hibernate-jpa as well

Comment: @lug - what's the exception? Is is the same? Have you clean-deployed?

Comment: @lgu and you are sure that spring-orm is in WEB-INF/lib? And you've cleared the logs?

Answer (score 0):

More importantly, you're missing the hibernate core dependencies for your project.

See how you can get them from [here](http://hibernate.org/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

```
These are the dependancies your need:
<dependency org="org.hibernate.javax.persistence" name="hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" rev="1.0.1.Final" conf="runtime->default;compile->default;test->default"/>   
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate" rev="3.5.4-Final" conf="compile->default;test->default;runtime->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-annotations" rev="3.5.4-Final" conf="runtime->default;compile->default;test->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-commons-annotations" rev="3.2.0.Final" conf="runtime->default;compile->default;test->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.2.0.Final" conf="runtime->default;compile->default;test->default"/>
<dependency org="cglib" name="cglib-nodep" rev="2.2.2" conf="runtime->default;compile->default;test->default"/>
```

In Ivy format.